# AutoComplete widget does not show all the data

Tags: android, emulation, autocompletetextview

I am working on an android project which uses `AutoCompleteTextView` widget which get populated from the **`db`**. In **Emulator** while testing it shows all the data in list. But when I test it on a device it does not list all the data after I enter first 3 characters. I don't know what the problem is.

```
productTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.prodName_CB);
    productTextView.setThreshold(2);
    ClearableEditText.createClearableWidget(productTextView, x);
    productTextView.setTypeface(tf);
```

Comment: put log cat to view error

Comment: i dont get any error, as i mentioned it shows all the data on the emulator,but on the phone it does not show the data.i dont get any error as such